# communication with subprocess using pipe created by os.pipe

Tags: python, c++, subprocess

Our testcase creates a pipe, starts a C++ binary as subprocess (pass the write file descriptor as argument to subprocess), waits for C++ binary to write something to the pipe. We are not using stdout / stderr for this as we are using those to read the output, errors of the C++ binary.

Below is python code:

```
import os
import subprocess

def main():
   r, w = os.pipe()

   cpp_path = "../bin/cpp_engine"
   cpp_process = subprocess.Popen([cpp_path, "-v", "-p", str(w)])

   r = os.fdopen(r)
   stg = r.read()
   print("test reads : ", stg)

   cpp_process.kill()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is C++ code where I am writing to pipe.

```
#include <lyra/lyra.hpp>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{    
   auto intgTestPipe = -1;

   auto cli = lyra::cli();

   cli.add_argument(
      lyra::opt(verboseFlag).name("-v").name("--verbose").help("enable verbose flag") |

      lyra::opt(intgTestPipe, "Integraion test Pipe")
         .name("-p")
         .name("--pipe")
         .help("Integration test pipe to communicate"));

   auto result = cli.parse({argc, argv});

   if (!result) {
      std::cout << "Error in command line: " << result.message() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   std::cout << intgTestPipe << " " << typeid(intgTestPipe).name() << std::endl;

   if (intgTestPipe != -1) {
      std::cout << "in intgTestPipe" << std::endl;
      auto fp = fdopen(intgTestPipe, "w");
      std::string msg = "sending message\n";

      if (fp != NULL) {
         fputs(msg.c_str(), fp);
      }
      else {
         std::cout << "Invalid file pointer" << std::endl;
      }

      fclose(fp);

      return 0;
   }
}
```

When I run python test, it is getting hung while reading from pipe. I think C++ binary is unable to write to the passed file descriptor.

output:

```
4 i
in cpp intgTestPipe
Invalid file pointer
```

Not sure why I am getting bad file descriptor even though I am passing the write file descriptor from the pipe.

Is there is any issue with this program or how to communicate from C++ to python using pipe other than stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone please help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: _I think C++ binary is unable to write to the passed file descriptor._ If you put in some error checking, you might find out.

Comment: @DrewDormann : I couldn't believe I got downvote because I posted "can someone please help me" in my question. Anyway I rephrased the question.

Comment: @PaulSanders : I used the suggestion and it is returning bad file descriptor.

Comment: We really need to see all your c++ code. You're passing the fd to the program in argv. We need to see how you're parsing that and opening it. It may not be valid in the subprocess due to close-on-exec flag. Why have python do both pipe and open syscalls as popen already creates a pipe? Unless I don't understand how python popen differs from the syscall

Comment: @CraigEstey : I updated C++ code.

Comment: I'm not a pythonista at alll. but shouldn't it be `cpp_process = subprocess.Popen([cpp_path, "-v", "-p", str(r)])`?  Also, I would print out the pipe fd in both the python code and the C++ code to check that they're the same.

Comment: @PaulSanders : I think the first file descriptor is read and second one is for write. As C++ is going to write in to the pipe, I passed 'w' instead of 'r'. Also I verified that file descriptors on Python and C++ are same.

Comment: OK, sorry, that makes sense.